# Using dictionary and dataframe to create new arrays with variable names with loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, dictionary

I am currently working to process some data that are imported to Python as a dataframe that has 10000 rows and 20 columns. The columns store sample names and chemical element. The daaaframe is currently indexed by both sample name and time, appearing as so: 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7knqD.png .

From this dataframe, I want to create individual arrays for each individual sample, of which there are around 25, with a loop. I have generated an index and array of the sample names, which yields an array that appears as so

`samplename = fuegodataframe.index.levels[0]`
`samplearray = samplename.to_numpy()`

array(['AC4-EUH41', 'AC4-EUH79N', 'AC4-EUH79S', 'AC4-EUH80', 'AC4-EUH81',
       'AC4-EUH81b', 'AC4-EUH82N', 'AC4-EUH82W', 'AC4-EUH84',
       'AC4-EUH85N', 'AC4_EUH48', 'AC4_EUH48b', 'AC4_EUH54N',
       'AC4_EUH54S', 'AC4_EUH60', 'AC4_EUH72', 'AC4_EUH73', 'AC4_EUH73W',
       'AC4_EUH78', 'AC4_EUH79E', 'AC4_EUH79W', 'AC4_EUH88', 'AC4_EUH89',
       'bhvo-1', 'bhvo-2', 'bir-1', 'bir-2', 'gor132-1', 'gor132-2',
       'gor132-3', 'sc ol-1', 'sc ol-2'], dtype=object)

I have also created a dictionary with keys of each of these variable names. I am now wondering how I would use this dictionary to generate individual variables for each of these samples that capture all the rows in which a sample is found.

I have tried something along these lines:

```
for ii in sampledictionary.keys():
     if ii == sampledictionary[ii]: 
        sampledictionary[ii] = fuegodataframe.loc[sampledictionary[ii]]
```

but this fails. How would I actually go about doing something like this? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how to generate variables dynamically rather than assign your output to a key in your dictionary.

In Python there is a globals function `globals()` that will output all the variable names defined in the document.

You can assign new variables dynamically to this dictionary

```
globals()[f'variablename_{ii}'] = fuegodataframe.loc[sampledictionary[ii]]
```

etc.

if `ii` was `0` then `variablename_0` would be available with the assigned value.

In general this is not considered good practice but it is required sometimes.

Comment: clever and sometimes useful

Comment: globals() is a dictionary so it can be added to: 
`>>> cheat`
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'cheat' is not defined `>>> type(globals())`<class 'dict'>
`>>> globals()['cheat'] = 123` 
`>>> cheat 123`
 
p.s likewise for locals()